How to run ffmpeg.wasm directly on the main thread (usacase: cloudflare worker, browser extension service worker, etc)
I am trying to run ffmpeg wasm on a cloudflare worker with a custom build. But since I can't start a web worker from within a CF worker I get the error

Worker is not defined

Is there a way to run ffmpeg.wasm on the main thread (in my case directly in the CF worker)?
I am running ./build-with-docker.sh to build a very small version of ffmpeg.wasm. By following this blog post - link. The final wasm file is only 8.4 mb (2.8 mb gzipped). CF Worker can support upto 10 MB compressed.
Here is the code for the worker
import { FFmpeg } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';
import { fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/util';

export interface Env {
    // Add any environment variables here
}

export default {
    async fetch(request: Request, env: Env, ctx: ExecutionContext): Promise<Response> {
        if (request.method !== 'POST') {
            return new Response('Send a POST request with a video file', { status: 400 });
        }

        const formData = await request.formData();
        const videoFile = formData.get('video') as File | null;

        if (!videoFile) {
            return new Response('No video file provided', { status: 400 });
        }

        try {
            const trimmedVideo = await trimVideo(videoFile);
            if (!trimmedVideo) {
                return new Response(`Failed to trim video`, { status: 500 });
            }
            return new Response(trimmedVideo, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
                    'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="trimmed_${videoFile.name}"`,
                },
            });
        } catch (error) {
            // @ts-ignore
            return new Response(`Error processing video: ${error.message}`, { status: 500 });
        }
    },
};

async function trimVideo(videoFile: File): Promise<Uint8Array | null> {
    const ffmpeg = new FFmpeg();
    try {
        await ffmpeg.load({
            coreURL: 'http://localhost:8787/ffmpeg-core.js',
            wasmURL: 'http://localhost:8787/ffmpeg-core.wasm',
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // @ts-ignore
        console.error(error.message);
        return null;
    }

    const inputFileName = 'input.mp4';
    const outputFileName = 'output.mp4';

    ffmpeg.writeFile(inputFileName, await fetchFile(videoFile));

    await ffmpeg.exec([
        '-i',
        inputFileName,
        '-ss',
        '1', // Start at 1 second
        '-to',
        '-1', // End 1 second before the end
        '-c',
        'copy', // Use the same codec (faster)
        outputFileName,
    ]);

    const data = await ffmpeg.readFile(outputFileName);
    await ffmpeg.deleteFile(inputFileName);
    await ffmpeg.deleteFile(outputFileName);

    return new Uint8Array(data as ArrayBuffer);
}

